aiohttp adds ~100 seconds latency?
I am sending a basic post request from a client to a server. The logs on my server show that the response took 9.41 seconds, but the logs on the client show that it took ~100 seconds.
Here is my code
logger.info("Uploading %s messages to backend.", len(messages))
st = time.time()
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.post(
        base_url + f"messages/",
        json=payload,
        headers=_auth_headers,
    ) as response:
        results = await response.json()
    et = time.time()
    logger.info(
        f"{len(results)} messages created in backend in {et-st:.2f} seconds.",
    )

Client logs
2024-10-28 07:05:36,319 [INFO] Uploading 104 messages to backend.
2024-10-28 07:07:12,952 [INFO] 104 messages created in backend in 96.63 seconds.

Server logs
api/messages/   POST    201 9.41301 28 Oct 2024 07:05:45

Any idea why would aiohttp add this overhead? Is it somehow getting stuck in the session? It doesn't seem to happen always, but usually happens if my requests take more than a few seconds..

Is there some other async task running which is preventing aiohttp from resuming its execution…?

So what your logs are telling you is that your request is 9.41s to reach your server endpoint. Then you only get the response after 85s or so. This can be related to several things : as mentioned by deceze, if you have a concurrent async task, it could prevent you from fetching the response before it's finished. An additional cause could be network latency + server processing time. if a message is taking ~10s to travel, on the 100s, 20% are caused by the network. Now if the server takes 80s to process your message, it adds up.

Also, if it takes that long to receive the message, I'm assuming it's a very large payload. So, possibly time taken to JSON decode could be a factor (try response.read() to rule that out).

Thanks all for the comments. Lrx, to clarify, the server takes 9.41 to process and return a response. Network time is not part of this. I can't imagine network time being more than a couple of 100ms.
deceze - there might be, but I thought the whole point of asyncio was to handle this, so if I have a long running task, others can resume execution while the larger tasks is running. How can I check / debug this?
Sam - I had no idea json decode can take so long. But since it doesn't always happen (sometimes the same / similar payload will take only 15 seconds), I doubt it is the json decode

Async is cooperative multitasking. While one task isn’t running/is awaiting something, something else can run. But it’s still just one thing running at any one time.
